# Kotlin :Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: kotlin

I am using kotlin ,and I get these error when I add the third library:
** implementation 'com.github.AsynctaskCoffee:tinderlikecardstack:1.0'**

from:  https://github.com/AsynctaskCoffee/TinderLikeCardStack

The Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.AsynctaskCoffee:tinderlikecardstack:1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/AsynctaskCoffee/tinderlikecardstack/1.0/tinderlikecardstack-1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/AsynctaskCoffee/tinderlikecardstack/1.0/tinderlikecardstack-1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/AsynctaskCoffee/tinderlikecardstack/1.0/tinderlikecardstack-1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**And my guild.gradle(:app)**

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gearsrun.stackviewapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.AsynctaskCoffee:tinderlikecardstack:1.0'

}
```

**build.grandle:**

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**my gradle.properties:**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Could anyone take a look what was going on please ,thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.AsynctaskCoffee:TinderLikeCardStack:1.0'
}
```

Normally, your declarations are true but you may declare them on wrong places. implementation part should be in Gradle app - maven declaration should be in main Gradle.

You can also define project with maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.AsynctaskCoffee</groupId>
    <artifactId>TinderLikeCardStack</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Also please check you should disable offline Gradle build. You can also download project and import as module.